# Click button automatically in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, buttonclick

I have a Jframe and a JButton on it which is a "Browse" button.I want the button to be clicked automatically when I run the program and perform its function, that is, open a browser for choosing files.
Please Help.
Here is my code:

```
package MyPackage;
public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
    initComponents();
    }
    private void BrowseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

     JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
     int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
     if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
     File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(selectedFile);//<-- here
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

} 

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
               new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The stated requirement is quite illogical. If it is a logical action to perform on start-up, there is no need for the button at all! But let's assume that the user might have cause to click the button later as well. Redefine the method of `private void BrowseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` to simply `private void BrowseActionPerformed()` then change `initComponents();` to `initComponents(); BrowseActionPerformed();` General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). ..

Comment: .. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically click a JButton button use:

```
 button.doClick()
```

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, a *great* answer would start with *"Don't do it, but instead.."* See [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't see how "Don't do it, but instead.." is relevant to this question. The question did not offer a way to do it. Please post an example answer.

Comment: *"The question did not offer a way to do it."* If the question asker offered an alternative, or instead couched the question in a more general way e.g. "best way to have an action invoked at start-up?", it (don't do it) would hardly be relevant! This is often an example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).. As to *me* putting an answer, I made a comment and am waiting for the OP to come round to the possibility that they are going about this the wrong way, rather than rushing in with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

write Browse.doClick(); at your constructor.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, a *great* answer would start with *"Don't do it, but instead.."* See [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer) for more details.